# Finding $P(X\in A)$ given description of $X$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Consider a random variable $X$ defined on $[0,1]$ as follows: $$X(\omega)=1,\space\space\space\space\space\space \space0\leq\omega<\dfrac{1}{4}$$$$X(\omega)=2\omega^2,\space\space\space\space\space\space\dfrac{1}{4}\leq\omega<\dfrac{3}{4}$$$$X(\omega)=\omega^2,\space\space\space\space\space\space\dfrac{3}{4}\leq\omega\leq1$$ Assume that $P$ is the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Determine $P(X\in[0,1])$ and $P(X\in[\frac{1}{2},1])$.

I am not sure how to do this problem. Actually this is the first type of problem I am facing. I realized that $P(X\in[0,1])=P(\omega\in[0,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}])+P(\omega\in[\dfrac{3}{4},1])$. But what distribution does $\omega$ follow?

Comment: You can indeed only calculate this if on $\Omega=[0,1]$ a probability measure has been given. Uniform maybe? Have a second look at the source of this question.

Comment: It is just given Lebesgue measure but I don't really know how to proceed.

Comment: I edited the question. Sorry I forgot to add "Lebesgue measure" was there.

Comment: That's enough then. What is the Lebesguemeasure of set $[0,\frac1{\sqrt2}]\cup[\frac34,1]$?

Comment: I don't know what Lebesgue measure is!!

Comment: Our professor had introduced Lebesgue measure as a modified form of integration. So I was thinking about integrating things but it can't be applied here.

Comment: But if you are asking for the Lebesgue measure, I am sorry I have not yet studied it.

Comment: $\omega$ does not follow any distribution. The random variable $X : \omega \mapsto X(\omega)$ follows a distribution. By the way, your "$P(X\in[0,1])=P(\omega\in[0,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}])+P(\omega\in[\dfrac{3}{4},1])$" has no meaning if it isn't a typo.

Comment: @yedaynara Just in short: the Lebesguemeasure of intervals $(a,b),[a,b),(a,b],[a,b]\subset[0,1]$ is $b-a$.

Comment: Oh thank you then. Then the solution is trivial. Just the sum of the measures of those two disjoint intervals.

Comment: Indeed. Success with your study.

Comment: @drhab We can pile up trivialities till heaven here, but "$P(X\in[0,1])=P(\omega\in[0,\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}])+P(\omega\in[\dfrac{3}{4},1])$" has still no meaning, as the LHS is the proba of the set $\{\omega|X(\omega)\in [0,1]\}$... You see. "$X(\omega)$ in", not "$\omega$ in". The whole point of probabiliities is to forgot the basis probability space $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mathbf{P})$, not to try to give sense to stuff involving elements in the events space. Subsets of the event space do matter.

Comment: Corrected the title and the statement of the exercise, at least now they are mathematically sound (but I left the rest unchanged, included the absurd $P(\omega\in\ldots)$).

Comment: $P(\{\omega|X(\omega)\in[a,b]\})=P(\omega\in X^{-1}[a,b])$. Is this not a correct statement? I am a beginner at these so maybe you can guide me how to write it.

Comment: @RobertGreen I admit that it's not completely 'kosher' and will remove my comments on you. I think it is not in the interest of the OP to go on with this. (you could say that $\omega\mapsto\omega$ is a random variable, so is connected to a distribution).

Comment: For any property $\mathfrak Q$ that each $\omega$ may or may not satisfy, one can consider $P(\mathfrak Q)=P(A)$ where $A=\{\omega\in\Omega\mid\mathfrak Q(\omega)\}$, but $P(\mathfrak Q(\omega))$ is not kosher. Thus $P(X\in[0,1])$ and $P(\{\omega\mid X(\omega)\in[0,1]\})$ are ok but $P(X(\omega)\in[0,1])$ is not.

Comment: I did not know know that "true" was being taboo, and that we were using "kosher" instead... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The figure below depicts $X$ as a function of $\omega$. Note that the measure is the Lebesgue measure this time.

[image]

If $0\le \omega\le \frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ or if $\frac{3}{4}\le \omega \le 1$ then $0\le X(\omega)\le1$. So $$\mathbb P(0\le X(\omega)\le1)=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{1}{4}.$$

As far as the second probability: $X\ge 1/2$ if $\omega\in A\cup B$. So  $$ \mathbb P( X\ge 1/2)= \mathbb P( A\cup B)=\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{4}.$$